# Failed to load image with using compass

Tags: html, css, sass, compass-sass

I'm currently doing website with Django framework. But,I met a problem to load image by using SASS. 
My code is here.(This is partial in scss code)

```
@import "compass/css3/images";
body {
       #site-footer{

      @include background-image(url('/static/main/images/continue.png'),
                                    linear-gradient(left, $left-color, $left-
                                    color 49%, $right-color 51%, $right-color));


   }
}
```

I use the '**backgorund-image**' in compass.
The problem is that image can't be loaded to webpage. I think that it may be needed to set the image path to somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does compile correctly:

```
body #site-footer {
  background-image: url("/static/main/images/continue.png"), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000, #ff0000 49%, #0000ff 51%, #0000ff);
  background-image: url("/static/main/images/continue.png"), -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000, #ff0000 49%, #0000ff 51%, #0000ff);
  background-image: url("/static/main/images/continue.png"), -o-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000, #ff0000 49%, #0000ff 51%, #0000ff);
  background-image: url("/static/main/images/continue.png"), linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000, #ff0000 49%, #0000ff 51%, #0000ff);
}
```

The problem might be that you provide incorrect path.

Please check manually whether the image is available:

http://example.com/static/main/images/continue.png

Comment: I wanna load to image from my drive..It's means that like this - d:/mysite/static/main/images - not from http://localhost/static/~ . My current situation is loaded from http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/main/images ~ .

Comment: The matter is that you've got some kind of web server software serving your project on port 8000. So your issue is not a matter of CSS or SASS or Compass. You have to understand how your web server and app work and how to serve static content with them. Please refer to the documentation of whatever framework you're using. PS Don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to relative_assets being set to false in config.rb. Try changing it to true.

Comment: Yes. You just need to uncomment the line.